# How to use javascript to print table dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I want print a table dynamically, but my program displayed in a messy way.
I hope each row conludes two elements. I want to display the table like this. In 1s it gets a name and display it. And in next 1s it gets another name and display it. By repeating in this way, display all data.Here is my main code.

```
  var count = 0;
  function AddTd(id, showname)
  {
    console.log(id);
    if(id == 0)   // if this is in the first column
    {
      var str = '<tr><td width="10px">'+showname+'</td>';
      $("#datashow").append(str);
      count = 1;  //  next element should in second column
      return;
    }
    if(id == 1)   // if this is in the second column
    {
      var str = '<td width="10px">'+showname+'</td></tr>';
      $("#datashow").append(str);
      count = 0;  //  next element should in first column
      return;
    }
  }

  setInterval('change()',50); // In function change, print the table dynamically
```

Comment: Where is function `change()`?

Comment: Just like this. function change() { AddTd(count, data); }

Answer (score 0):

This should create table with as many elements as there will be in array and do 2 columns per row.

http://jsfiddle.net/XfKME/3/

```
 var names = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"];
 var tbody = "<table>";
 $.each(names, function (i, item) {
     if (i % 2 == 0)
         tbody += "<tr>";

     tbody += "<td>";
     tbody += item;
     tbody += "</td>"

     if (i % 2 == 1)
         tbody += "</tr><br />";

 });

 tbody += "</table>";
```

Comment: No. I want to display the table like this. In 1s it gets a name and display it. And in next 1s it gets another name and display it. By repeating in this way, display all data.

Comment: Your name count should match the cell count. If it does then check update.

Comment: I don't count the name, because I just display it one by one. And the number of name must be %2 == 0